# Why is SQLAlchemy changing a string to an integer after flushing changes to the database?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have defined an SQLAlchemy Table object to have a column attribute of type `Text`.  I then create an instance of the table object and set the column attribute to be a string of digits.  The attribute definitely starts out as a string, however after `flush` is called with a database session the attribute gets changed to an integer. Why would SQLAlchemy change this attribute to be an integer when the attribute is supposed to be a text string?

This is for Python 3.6.7, SQLAlchemy 1.3.6, and MySQL 8.0.15.

Here is the table definition:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text

Base = declarative_base()

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Entry'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Text, nullable=True)
```

Here is how the table class is used:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

database_uri = "SOME_MYSQL_URI"

db_engine = create_engine(database_uri, pool_recycle=3600)

session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        autocommit=True,
        autoflush=False,
        bind=db_engine
    )
)

entry = Entry(value='0123') 
session.add(entry)
session.flush()
```

You can see `entry.value` change after the flush method is called in the terminal:

```py
>>> entry.value 
'0123'

>>> type(entry.value)
<class 'str'>

>>> session.flush()

>>> entry.value
123

>>> type(entry.value)
<class 'int'>
```

It should be noted that the database saves the value as '0123' in the table.  It is the python interpreter that seems to be recasting the value an integer. Also, strings with non-digit characters seem to be unaffected.

Comment: I can't replicate (3.7.4/1.3.6/8.0.17), what dbapi are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using mysql-connector-python i.e. mysql+mysqlconnector. There is a slight difference in the sample code from what I am really using.  In my actual code, I am using `Entry` as a subclass of another class called `Element`. But I don't think that should make much of a difference in the column `value`.

Comment: That’s the same one as me so there is no reason why we should really get different results. What it really looks like to me is that the underlying column of `Entry.value` is actually an integer type - but you say you’ve checked that. The only other way I can think to replicate what you are seeing is by using a `@property` or some other mechanism to convert the value to an integer on access. But unless you can provide an example that actually replicates the issue, I’m just guessing.